# compare values across files

Tags: linux, unix, compare

Am new to linux commands. Help me with command/script with explanation to `return 1` if values(field2) of 1 file is lesser than the value(field2) in another file `else return 0`

Input:

file1.txt

```
AA 90  
BB 80.60  
CC 60.50
```

file2.txt

```
AA 98.60  
BB 88.76  
CC 100.90
```

Output:
file3.txt

```
AA 1  
BB 1  
CC 1
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor to mark data. Also, did you try anything? Add that to the original question also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){print $1, a[$1]<$2}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
AA 1
BB 1
CC 1
```

Explained some:

```
$ awk '                 # using awk
NR==FNR {               # process first file
    a[$1]=$2            # hash to a, $1 is the key
    next                # process the next record
}                       # second file processing follows
($1 in a) {             # if $1 was present in file1
    print $1, a[$1]<$2  # print $1 and 0/1 whether file1 entry was less or not
}' file1 file2
```